# stuck at [ok] started GNOME Display Manager.t Dispatcher Service.... after linux reboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, gnome, nomodeset

->I tried fixing with using nomodeset on grub and similar changes on grub. It didn’t work.
->I tired updating and upgrading in tty terminal but it did not work
->I tried updating from advanced remove option but it did not work either.
ps: i have dual boot and my laptop is hp

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS